# Broadcast Receiver call multiple time when change wifi state in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to implement the wifi change state feature in my Activity but I am getting multiple time calls in Receive.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private IStatusChangeListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        String status = getConnectivityStatusString(context);
        Log.d("network", status);
        if (status.isEmpty() || status.equals("Wifi enabled") || status.equals("Wifi enabled")) {
            listener.onConnected(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "NOt Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            listener.onConnected(false);
        }
    }

    public void myBrodCastReceiver(IStatusChangeListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

in my Activity :

```
lateinit var myReceiver: MyReceiver
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_r3_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarmain)
        val radius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.roundcorner)
        txtRove.text = getString(R.string.txt_live_video)
        myReceiver = MyReceiver()
        myReceiver.myBrodCastReceiver(this)
}

 override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
       this.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }
```

in my Android manifest file :

```
  <receiver android:name = "com.rovedashcam.newmodeule.base.wifirecciver.MyReceiver" android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
                        tools:ignore="BatteryLife" />
                    <action android:name = "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

when I try to get the run code then I get multiple time calls back in MyReceiver class onReceive method I have to register the broadcast Receiver from one place and unregister from `onpause` method but I don't know why it's calling two times please help me in this.

Comment: What is the target SDK for this app?

Answer (score 0):

You have registered the `BroadcastReceiver` twice. Once in the manifest and again in code. You only need to do the one or the other. If you want to register your `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically (in code), then remove the `<receiver>` declaration from the manifest.